# Swapping two style-sheets CSS file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox, stylesheet, swap

I am writing a web-app for a mobile device, what I am doing is to change dynamically the css and store that option for the user, I have been looking all night long, googling methods and way to achieve my objective but nothing worked for me.

This is the type of button that I am using, and here comes up another problem, because I wasn't able to Check and Uncheck the checkbox.

HTML

```
<input id="#checkbox" type="checkbox" checked onclick="swapStyleSheet()">
```

The only thing that worked fine for me is this:

```
<head>    
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="default.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
            document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href',sheet);
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

and in the body

```
<input id="#checkbox" type="checkbox" checked onclick="swapStyleSheet("Second.css")">
```

But this is not dynamically because once the user taps the button is not able to go back and I am not sure that works on a mobile device

Any suggestion how to proceed?

Comment: I would not recommend swapping stylesheets. Rather Change the class of a body tag.

Comment: Why don't  you recommend swapping stylesheets? and why change the class of a body tag?

Comment: You're making making more problems that way. Loading additional files, writing to DOM both can be unpredictable in behaviour and performance. Browsers have been optimised to apply styles based on classes, please use that. @Stephan Strate has provided a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the quotes around `Second.css`

```
onclick="swapStyleSheet('Second.css')"
```

Without quotes, it's a syntax error (but your console is already telling you this).

Answer (score -1):

Here there is an exemptional [link](https://www.inetsolution.com/INETSOLUTION/media/pdfs/inetsolution-styleswitcher-howto.pdf) that shows step by step how to how to switch two CSS sheet-file

But for the type of input, I am not sure how you can do

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend to change your stylesheets like this.
Here are my reasons why:

1. Loading another file will probably cause a "hard" transition between your two styles. You writing a mobile web-app, so imagine someone with unstable internet connection loads your application. Your web-app will be unstyled for a couple of seconds.
2. Browser needs to load another file (if you want to switch back, it will probably load the original file again, depending on cache settings)
3. Can be solved much easier with `.scss` for example (but also with plain `.css`). I have got an example for you down below. You can even add transitions, so your changes are much more pleasant.

```js
function rotateStyle () {
  document.body.id = document.body.id == 'alternate' ? '' : 'alternate';
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  /* you could also add transitions */
  transition: background-color 2s;
}

body#alternate {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- your content -->
  
  <button onclick="rotateStyle()">Change your style</button>
</body>
```